# Calculate the difference in dates between rows and group by category Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set of customers and dates of purchases where multiple customers have made purchases on different days.  I would like to find the average difference in days between purchases for each customer.

```
Cust     Date
A        01/01/2019
B        01/01/2019
B        01/01/2019
A        03/01/2019
B        02/01/2019
A        05/01/2019
```

The intermediate df could be the differences:

```
A     B
2     0
2     1
```

This could then be used to calculate the averages for each customer
Note that some purchases may occur on the same day so a 0 will be recorded.

The final DF will look like this:

```
Customer     No.of Purchases     AVG diff
A            3                   1
B            3                   0.5
```

I understand the process but am having trouble with the code.  The number of unique customers is 100+ so I would need some code that can work this out for many customers.  I am guessing I would have to loop through the data and store the intermediate values somehow but I am not sure how this can be done in python.

Any help or guidance would be apreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your dates `datetime` and `sort` so you are calculating the correct difference. Then `groupby` each customer to get the calculations you want:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
df = df.sort_values('Date')

def AVG_diff(x):
    # Integer number of Days
    return x.diff().mean().total_seconds()/86400

df.groupby('Cust').Date.agg(['size', AVG_diff])

#  Cust  size  AVG_diff
#0    A     3       2.0
#1    B     3       0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```py
# Sort the DataFrame by customerid and service_txn_date
df = df.sort_values(['customerid', 'service_txn_date'])

# Calculate the time difference between consecutive service transactions for each customer
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby('customerid')['service_txn_date'].diff()

# Calculate the average number of days for each customer to come back for a service
average_days_to_come_back = df.groupby('customerid')['time_diff'].mean()
```